# How to use HTML tag in product names

Tags: product, magento2.3

I have created an extension (with the help of Pawan - thank you) to change the product names dynamically.

What I try now, is to add HTML tags to the product names. Unfortunately, I don't get it working.

For example, instead of a break, the tag `<br>` is shown in my name. Help would be great!!

Comment: How are you calling your product name? There will be multiple places where names are called. Check `$block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true)` line of the code and add your allowed HTML tags there.

Comment: thank you for your help. I reached it with html_entity_decode.